# if webpage is being opened on a mobile device how to open phone call screen in react js web app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I had created a web app and i want if webpage is being opened on a mobile device how to open phone call screen in react js web app. How is it possible?

Comment: Good question, thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use `tel` inside `href` to open default caller application.

```
<a href="tel:+9971863733">Call: 9971863733</a>
```

Or use onClick handler on any element to call

```
onclick="window.open('tel:9971863733');"
```

Comment: @LB93 Mark it as an answer then.